# chrome extensions: full width toolbars

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im currently working on a fork of the famous web developer extension (chrome, firefox, opera). Exactly I am working on the chrome extension.

The Firefox extension is shown like that:
[image]

Chrome instead shows only a icon...
[image]

..which toggles the "pretty small" widget:
[image]

A part of my goal with this fork is to change this toggle icon to a toolbar such as firefox does.

After studying the documentation chrome extensions (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide) I came to the result that this is not possible with default settings (browser actions, page actions,...).

When I looked again at the Table of Contents in the documentation I got an idea. There is the possibility to edit the bookmarks. So it could be possible to add an additional bookmark bar/row and place the single web developer actions as bookmark with the function on it.

Is this the right way for solving this? Because at the moment I only see possibilities with more or less dirty hacks. And doing it via bookmarks seems at least dirty.

PS: I also thought about this:
The plugin is actually the same on firefox and chrome and from the same author. So when this adaption of the toolbar in chrome would be easy possible then would not have such differences in the chrome and firefox addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's simply impossible.

Chrome does not support custom toolbars, and that includes *"an additional bookmark bar/row"*.

The closest, visually, would be injecting UI directly into the top of all pages. I don't think I need to explain why *that* is hacky.